# Why would curl fail to resolve a URL when drill can?

Tags: arch-linux, dns, troubleshooting, resolv.conf

I am trying to configure my computer to resolve some domains using a local DNS server. The DNS server is at 192.168.1.123, and is itself able to resolve everything normally.

On other computers, I installed dnscrypt-proxy and changed `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 single-request-reopen
```

I also ensured that `/etc/resolv.conf` is not overwritten by NetworkManager.

I then edited `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml` so as to use `forwarding_rules` to forward `home.arpa` to 192.168.1.124. I have a GIT service running on this IP, and the DNS server at 192.168.1.123 is configured to resolve `git.home.arpa` to 192.168.1.124. idea is that I can open `git.home.arpa`.

When I use `host git.home.arpa` or `drill git.home.arpa`, both my desktop, my laptop and the DNS server at 192.168.1.123 all return the correct IP of 192.168.1.124. I can see the queries in the DNS server logs as well.

When I do `curl git.home.arpa` on the desktop and the DNS server, I see the correct HTML of the GIT service. However, on my laptop I get `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: git.home.arpa`. I get the same thing from browsers as well.

As far as I can tell, the laptop and desktop both have identical configuration. The following files are the same between them:

- `/etc/resolv.conf`
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
- `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml`
- `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/forwarding-rules.txt`

I tried rebooting the laptop, restarting the NetworkManager service, restarting dncrypt-proxy. Presumably there must be some difference, since one is working and the other is not, but I don't know where.

Why would curl fail to resolve a domain, if host and drill can resolve it? How can I find what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the laptop was running `systemd-resolved`. I was surprised by this, because:

- There was nothing in `nsswitch.conf`
- There was nothing in `resolv.conf`
- `dnscrypt-proxy.service` was installed and working

So I thought it couldn't possibly be that two resolvers are running side by side without breaking DNS. Turns out they were. Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708899/217968 I took another look and indeed it was disabled on the desktop, disabled on the DNS server, but enabled on the laptop. I corrected this with:

```
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

And the DNS on my laptop began working.